# Left padded table rows

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to mimic the following table layout using HTML/CSS:

[image: Left padded rows example]

**NOTE**: It's a table from LibreOffice Writer which I modified using Gimp to show you what I mean.

As you can see, I'd like to add some left padding to some rows to show visually that they are inside a group.

I tried using padding-left of both `<td>` and `<tr>`, and a little trick that don't work: applying '`border-left: 14px solid white`' to the `<tr>` and then '`border-left: 15px solid black`' to the first `<td>` in the row. I thought that the border in the `<td>` would overlap the `<tr>` border by 1px, but HTML rendering seems not to work that way :)

Also, I tried to do this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="9">
    GROUP 1
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="9" style="padding-left: 15px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> <!-- # --> </td>
        <td> <!-- Id --> </td>
        <td> <!-- Field1 --> </td>
        (ETC)
        <td> <!-- Comment --> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem with this approach is that the column lines of the  inside the 'group' don't match the ones that are outside so it doesn't look good...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Remove borders from table cells, instead add divs within each table cell with the border:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">
    <div class="cell">GROUP 1</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left: 15px">
    <div class="cell"> col 1</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="cell"> col 2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="cell"> col 3</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="cell"> col 4</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
div.cell {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
table td {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

See example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baMdWP

Comment: I think that this will work! Adding a div inside each cell shouldn't affect the performance too badly, should it? There are tables with more than 600 cells... Anyway, I'll give it a try and I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
.with-padding {
    margin-left: 10px;
}


<table class="normal">
...
</table>
<table class="with-padding">
...
</table>
<table class="normal">
...
</table>
```

Comment: I'd like to use only one table, but your suggestion is easy to implement... I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assign `padding-left: 15px` to every sub-sequent `<tr>` that is to be displayed as part of the group. It's better to use a class instead of applying inline style.

Comment: Yes, when I find a solution I'll use classes instead of inline styles, but applying 'padding-left' to the `<tr>` tags didn't work for me (I'm using Firefox 57 and Chome 63).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        GROUP 1
    </td>
</table>
<table style="width:95%;margin-left:5%">

    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">January</td>
        <td style="width:25%;">$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table,th,td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```